# Typescript Types: Type of object value which can be used as index signature

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I want to write a array to object function, which extracts one property as the index, like:

```
export const arrayToObject
    = <T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K] & string>(arr: T[], key: K): { [v: V]: T } =>
    Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(item => ({[item[key]]: item})));
```

But it gives a compile error saying `An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'` for `V`, although I constraint the `V` type to be `string`. Why is the error and what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`V` may extend `T[K]`. But since `T` is not constrained in any way when you index using `item[key]` all the compiler will know is that `item[key]` is of type `T[K]`. You need to constrain `T` so that for the key `K` the value will be of a type compatible with a property key.

```
export const arrayToObject
    = <T extends Record<K, V>, K extends keyof T, V extends PropertyKey>(arr: T[], key: K): { [v in T[K]]: T } =>
    Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(item => ({[item[key]]: item})));


let r = arrayToObject([{ key: "A", value: 0 }, { key: "B", value: 0 }], "key");
r.A.value //ok
r.B.value //ok
r.C.value //err
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wIZShgngFQgHkAjAK2ARgCg464BeOAHnzlBmGQBNU4AlStG7MA0gBo4ANQB8k0exCcefANbBcEAGZx8kqYuW84ABSgQwwWLlEaZACixQAXLoDaAXUnrcr0QEpXAG84NwA3OABLZHdRDw9XNgBfRhlaelIKKgA6DFRUSIBzZHsgpMlsyqdsgFsMMHtIzhrUuFK3JuAatx94106apP9hgG5qcYAbYHgoRjgnPEJMyhh7NxCfVwAiAEEtyTCMCYBXYFcABjhyuA2NbYAhfbhDk7O4S6SvOC2fLf8xqDZHbZF6nOAAenBEFU1EB9xBRzBkOhsOyAGEEa8IeCrFAgA)

Answer (score 0):

I also found an working solution, which seems a little bit lighter:

```
export const arrayToObject =
   <T extends {[k in K]: number | string}, K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], key: K): { [k in T[K]]: T } =>
      Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(item => ({ [item[key]]: item })));
```